# Ping and web requests have slow "startup" yet DNS, latency and speed tests are fast?

Tags: networking, dns

So the key symptom that makes me suspicious is that ping takes about a second or so to start printing when I run it on Ubuntu and starts almost immediately on an OSX laptop (I don't have ubuntu on a laptop, so OS is kind of possibly coincidence).

Normally I would suspect DNS but this is my Ubuntu DNS test:

```
dig +trace www.stackoverflow.com

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> +trace www.stackoverflow.com
;; global options: +cmd
;; Received 40 bytes from 10.0.0.1#53(10.0.0.1) in 7 ms
```

mtr, ping and speed test are all fine in their metrics. For example this is ping on the Ubuntu desktop:

```
ping www.stackoverflow.com
PING stackoverflow.com (151.101.1.69) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=9.87 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=8.95 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=9.17 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=8.83 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=9.14 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=9.08 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=9.16 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=9.03 ms
64 bytes from 151.101.1.69 (151.101.1.69): icmp_seq=9 ttl=57 time=8.91 ms
```

but the key thing is that it took nearly two seconds to start printing ping times.

I realize this *might* be something totally unrelated to Ubuntu but I am guessins that there might be some Linux internals or debugging knowledge here that might help.

I can look at the strace output of ping but not really sure what I am looking for. strace prints things and then hangs for two seconds while it is doing whatever it is doing. this is the output when I kill it at that point

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_mdns4_minimal.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
read(5, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0\240\23\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=18504, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 20496, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0) = 0x7f565ae48000
mmap(0x7f565ae49000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x1000) = 0x7f565ae49000
mmap(0x7f565ae4b000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x3000) = 0x7f565ae4b000
mmap(0x7f565ae4c000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x3000) = 0x7f565ae4c000
close(5)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f565ae4c000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f565ae4e000, 155550)          = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=155550, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 155550, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 5, 0) = 0x7f565ae4e000
close(5)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_dns.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 5
read(5, "\177ELF\2\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0>\0\1\0\0\0 #\0\0\0\0\0\0"..., 832) = 832
fstat(5, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=31176, ...}) = 0
mmap(NULL, 32984, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0) = 0x7f565ae3f000
mmap(0x7f565ae41000, 16384, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x2000) = 0x7f565ae41000
mmap(0x7f565ae45000, 4096, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x6000) = 0x7f565ae45000
mmap(0x7f565ae46000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 5, 0x6000) = 0x7f565ae46000
close(5)                                = 0
mprotect(0x7f565ae46000, 4096, PROT_READ) = 0
munmap(0x7f565ae4e000, 155550)          = 0
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM|SOCK_CLOEXEC|SOCK_NONBLOCK, IPPROTO_IP) = 5
setsockopt(5, SOL_IP, IP_RECVERR, [1], 4) = 0
connect(5, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(53), sin_addr=inet_addr("192.168.1.1")}, 16) = 0
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 0)    = 1 ([{fd=5, revents=POLLOUT}])
sendmmsg(5, [{msg_hdr={msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base=">\326\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\3www\rstackoverflow\3c"..., iov_len=39}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, msg_len=39}, {msg_hdr={msg_name=NULL, msg_namelen=0, msg_iov=[{iov_base="w\256\1\0\0\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\3www\rstackoverflow\3c"..., iov_len=39}], msg_iovlen=1, msg_controllen=0, msg_flags=0}, msg_len=39}], 2, MSG_NOSIGNAL) = 2
poll([{fd=5, events=POLLIN}], 1, 5000^C)  = ? ERESTART_RESTARTBLOCK (Interrupted by signal)
strace: Process 1242328 detached
```

Any ideas welcome.

**UPDATE:**

I now suspect it is the connection to the router/modem. But ther VERY strange thing is that the follow is *slow* on my Ubuntu desktop but normal on the laptops (OSX).

```
ping dsldevice.lan
PING dsldevice.lan (192.168.1.254) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from dsldevice.lan (192.168.1.254): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=2.08 ms
64 bytes from dsldevice.lan (192.168.1.254): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=1.89 ms
```

**UPDATE:**

After a lot of fooling around, running an apt update and restarting, it seems I am back to normal now. I looked at tcpdump before (when problem was occuring) and after and am not noticing much.

Still have no idea but now the problem is gone for the time being. Will update if it re-occurs. Seems like a good learning exercise.

**UPDATE: (This is getting long)**

For reference on the MTU questions, I am connecting from Ubuntu wirelessly to a netgear router that is wired to a plusnet fibre connection (using ADSL from the premises).

**UPDATE: Testing for mtu size as in https://mike632t.wordpress.com/2019/03/03/determine-mtu-size-using-ping/**

I think something is very wrong when I test mtu against 8.8.8.8? For larger sizes I get the "message too long" error but as I decrease the size the message no longer appaers but I get 100% packet loss until size 68=96-28. Maybe this is expected for some reason?

```
ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 1472(1500) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.254 icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1488)
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488

ping -s $((97 - 28)) -D 8.8.8.8 -c 1
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 69(97) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

ping -s $((96 - 28)) -D 8.8.8.8 -c 1
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 68(96) bytes of data.
[1620817285.571725] 76 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=10.7 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.680/10.680/10.680/0.000 ms
```

**UPDATE: another data point.**

I am suspecting this belongs more in a networking forum as I will find out this is nothing to do with the Ubuntu driver side of things as I had suspected earlier, but not sure yet

```
ping -c 3 -s $((1489 - 28)) -M do bbc.co.uk
PING bbc.co.uk (151.101.0.81) 1461(1489) bytes of data.
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488

--- bbc.co.uk ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 2037ms

ping -c 3 -s $((1488 - 28)) -M do bbc.co.uk
PING bbc.co.uk (151.101.0.81) 1460(1488) bytes of data.
1468 bytes from 151.101.0.81 (151.101.0.81): icmp_seq=1 ttl=58 time=11.8 ms
1468 bytes from 151.101.0.81 (151.101.0.81): icmp_seq=2 ttl=58 time=12.0 ms
1468 bytes from 151.101.0.81 (151.101.0.81): icmp_seq=3 ttl=58 time=10.7 ms

--- bbc.co.uk ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 2003ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 10.702/11.519/12.029/0.583 ms
```

**UPDATE:**

The result of the tracepath query as requested. This is at mtu 1500 setting. Note that the usual mtr tests are showing good speed and latency as well as few packets.

```
tracepath www.ebay.com
 1?: [LOCALHOST]                      pmtu 1488
 1:  www.routerlogin.com                                   1.048ms
 1:  www.routerlogin.com                                   1.003ms
 2:  dsldevice.lan                                         2.037ms
 3:  no reply
 4:  no reply
 5:  128.hiper04.sheff.dial.plus.net.uk                   10.954ms asymm  7
 6:  peer3-et3-1-1.slough.ukcore.bt.net                   85.034ms asymm  7
 7:  peer2-xe8-0-2.telehouse.ukcore.bt.net                25.399ms asymm  8
 8:  no reply
 9:  no reply
10:  no reply
11:  no reply
```

**UPDATE:**

Just to confirm, mtu is set to 1500.

```
ip link | grep wlxa09f10b9ff56
3: wlxa09f10b9ff56: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
```

**UPDATE: complete log of the ping tests against 8.8.8.8**

```
$ ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 1472(1500) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.254 icmp_seq=1 Frag needed and DF set (mtu = 1488)
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3028ms


$ ping -c 4 -M do -s 1462 8.8.8.8 # may show fragmentation
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 1462(1490) bytes of data.
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488
ping: local error: message too long, mtu=1488

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 3049ms


$ ping -c 4 -M do -s 1452 8.8.8.8 # no fragmentation?
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 1452(1480) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3003ms


$ ping -c 4 -M do -s 1453 8.8.8.8 # still no fragmentation?
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 1453(1481) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3005ms


$ ping -c 4 -M do -s 69 8.8.8.8 
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 69(97) bytes of data.

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 3004ms


$ ping -c 4 -M do -s 68 8.8.8.8 
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 68(96) bytes of data.
76 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=60.2 ms
76 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=9.07 ms
76 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=3 ttl=116 time=8.89 ms
76 bytes from 8.8.8.8: icmp_seq=4 ttl=116 time=9.04 ms

--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.887/21.802/60.215/22.177 ms
```

**UPDATE**:

For what it is worth I am "on fibre" on Plusnet but with a short ADSL connection (that is what they tell me anyway). According to this thread that means the Plusnet router defaults to 1500 and I have everything upstream (netgear router, ubuntu desktop) set to 1500 as well.

[https://community.plus.net/t5/Fibre-Broadband/Maximum-MTU-for-PPPOE/td-p/1214123#:~:text=For%20what%20it's%20worth%3A,to%20a%20MTU%20of%201500](https://community.plus.net/t5/Fibre-Broadband/Maximum-MTU-for-PPPOE/td-p/1214123#:%7E:text=For%20what%20it%27s%20worth%3A,to%20a%20MTU%20of%201500).

Comment: Sounds like you have a MTU problem, as you have DSL. What is your MTU set to? Does your problem occur on a wired connection, or wireless?

Comment: @heynnema MTU misconfigurations are so prevalent that I have a canned answer.

Comment: @waltinator I also have a canned answer, but I'm waiting to hear back from OP first. 1492 is a common setting for DSL, but it may not always be correct. My procedure accommodates variations in finding the correct setting.

Comment: @heynnema  I just checked and MTU is 1500 ... again it is a bit frustating for you (and everyone helping) as the bad behaviour is gone for the time being so very hard to diagnose unless you have an idea that something is still observable in settings.

Comment: Since you have DSL, I can pretty much guarantee that a 1500 MTU setting is wrong. Let me put up an answer for you to follow to determine the correct setting. You didn't answer my question about if you're using a wired or wireless connection.

Comment: Install `iputils-tracepath` and then do `tracepath www.ebay.com` and edit that output into your question. Report back. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: @heynnema sorry I didn't see all the questions in the thread. Yes I am using a wireless connection. Going to change the mtu setting now and try some tests and will post back.

Comment: @heynnema I am on plusnet and in this forum here: https://community.plus.net/t5/ADSL-Broadband/MTU-settings/td-p/1105407#:~:text=For%20PPPoA%2C%20as%20used%20on,get%20problems%20with%20some%20sites. It is indicated that 1500 is correct. I am guessing that I should be checking my router AS WELL as the plusnet router for settings (I plug my main netgear router via ethernet into the plusnet adsl router and I connect wirelessly to the netgear from my devices)

Comment: @heynnema I am seeing something is quite wrong with the MTU tests only working for MTU as the smallest amount (68). I will be debugging/googling this. If anyone knows what this is off hand let me know.

Comment: Did you install `iputils-tracepath` and do the command that I indicated? Do that now and report back. I can't help you if you don't follow my instructions. I've posted an answer to help set MTU... but let's see the results of the tracepath first.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: @heynnema Sorry for the delay, updated the question now (at the bottom) with the tracepath to ebay. From my usual tests (mtr and noticing any dns delays) everything seems fine now but maybe you will notice something amiss there in the results.

Comment: @mathtick Is the MTU setting in your connection profile set to 1500, or 1488? Your ping log uses `-s $((1489 - 28))` which doesn't follow my MTU procedure.

Comment: @heynnema there are a few mtu sequences shown above. Basically there are *two changes* across the size spectrum. One occurs at 1489 - 28 whre that message stop appearing but I still get 100% packet loss against 8.8.8.8 and the other change is at 68 where the packet loss stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is with the MTU setting for your DSL connection.

There's a MTU setting in Ubuntu's network configuration, and a WAN MTU setting in your router.

For DSL, a common MTU setting is 1492. Just go ahead and try this value first and see if your web sites are now accessible.

To determine the correct setting, start with all MTU settings = 1500 and VPN = off. (VPN requires different testing).

In the `terminal`:

ping [-c count] [-M do] [-s packet_size] [host]

The options used are:

- `c count`: number of times to ping
- `M hint`: Select Path MTU Discovery strategy.  may be either `do` (prohibit fragmentation, even local one), `want` (do PMTU discovery, fragment locally when packet size is large), or `dont` (do not set DF flag).
- `s packet_size`: Specifies the number of data bytes to be sent.

You should always start at 1472 and work your way down by 10 each time. Once you get a reply, go up by 1 until you get a fragmented packet. Take that value (last good value) and add 28 to the value to account for the various TCP/IP headers. Eg. let's say that 1452 was the proper packet size (where you first got an ICMP reply to your ping). The actual MTU size would be 1480, which is the optimum for the network we're working with.

`ping -c 4 -M do -s 1472 8.8.8.8` # this will probably show fragmentation

`ping -c 4 -M do -s 1462 8.8.8.8` # may show fragmentation

`ping -c 4 -M do -s 1452 8.8.8.8` # no fragmentation?

`ping -c 4 -M do -s 1453 8.8.8.8` # still no fragmentation?

reference: [How to determine the proper MTU size with ICMP pings](http://muzso.hu/2009/05/17/how-to-determine-the-proper-mtu-size-with-icmp-pings)

Comment: I one of my updates I go through this ping mtu test against 8.8.8.8. Curiously the "message too long" errors starts appearing at 1461 but below that I get 100% packet loss until going down to 68 or below. Do you know if that is that expected?

Comment: @mathtick Show me a log of your entire test. Edit it into your question.

Comment: Yep, I've now put the entire logs of the ping tests and two extra tests at 69, 68 to show the transition from 100% to 0% packet loss that I was talking about earlier. See the "update" with 8.8.8.8 in the heading

Comment: @mathtick Thanks for the additional logs. Maybe "short" ADSL works a little different from regular DSL, with regards to MTU. What I don't understand is the `tracepath` showing MTU of 1488. I don't know where that's coming from. So... I'm confused, and have no further ideas for you. Sorry.

Comment: Thanks. It is quite strange. Will post back if I ever find a reason for this. I am still not clear on if the ping test's 100% packet loss after the "message too long" disappears is meaningfull.